# Extend angularUI popover directive to create a confirm popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a easy confirm popover when in angularJS. I'm already using AngularUI for many other components which is why it seems like the natural choice to extend.

I have created a example in plnkr but essential I would like to be able to simply add a confirm to a button like this...

```
<button confirm="Are you sure you want to delete what ever" confirm-func="deleteThing()" confirm-placement="right" confirm-title="Are you sure?" class="btn btn-default">Delete?    </button>
```

and this works and produces the popover with a cancel or confirm by using my own template. But i need to be able to pass through what ever function in the "confirm-func" attribute to run on confirmation click. What ever I do I can't get it to work. Here is my directive that extends the angularUI...

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']).directive( 'confirmPopup', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: { title: '@', content: '@', placement: '@', animation: '&', isOpen: '&', func: '&' },
    templateUrl: 'confirmPopup.html',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
      $scope.confirm = function(){

        $scope.func();//here is where we want to run the function, but it does not work!
        $scope.$parent.tt_isOpen = false;
      }
      $scope.cancel = function(){
        $scope.$parent.tt_isOpen = false;
      }
    }
  };
})
.directive( 'confirm', [ '$tooltip', function ($tooltip) {
    return $tooltip( 'confirm', 'confirm', 'click' );
}]);
```

Plunkr example attached: http://plnkr.co/edit/W9BWMc3x5khuaMEL7lp1?p=preview

Comment: `$tooltip` service, as far as I understand it, wasn't designed with the aim of opening up the implementation and allowing extension. Rather, it was a nice way for internal code sharing between `popup` and `tooltip` (and possibly other directives). I, unfortunately, do not see a easy and direct way of doing this without passing in a compiled element to `content` as `$compile(toolTipContent)(scope)`. However, this is a substantial change needed in `angular.ui`.

Comment: How would one go about doing this? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer to your specific question, but I was looking to do something similar in my project (a simple directive for a confirmation popover) and ended up going with the solution from this blog post:

http://wegnerdesign.com/blog/angular-js-directive-tutorial-on-attribute-bootstrap-confirm-button/

It has been working out fairly well for me.  I've modified it slightly to make it possible to apply custom CSS classes via an attribute. My modifications are here:

https://github.com/sergkr/swot/blob/master/client/directives/confirmButton.js

Example usage:

```
<button type="button" confirm-button="deleteQuestion($index)" message="Are you sure you want to remove this question?"></button>
```

And a screenshot of this directive in action:

[image: Confirmation popover screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunatly while this is a solution it's not ideal as it relies on jQuery and not AngularUI

Comment: @NimmoNet doesn't bootstrap rely on jQuery? It should be in your project already...

Comment: @Sergey K How can i adjust the offset of your directive? when i use "left" position, it will overlap with the button, so i want to move it more left.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to pass the confirm-func argument directly. You need your own implementation of tooltip directive instead of $tooltip service. There is dirty solution, but I can not recommend this way:

You can use

```
$scope.$parent.deleteThing();
```

instead of

```
$scope.func();//here is where we want to run the function, but it does not work!
```

Comment: This would not work as the function passed in could be anything depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do what you need, even if it feel a bit hackish.
I've made a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/9oOBUmIJiF6fUBdIFl8q?p=info)

Basically, the trick is to inject a controller of you own to the fresh directive instance
that $tooltip returns.

```
var tt = $tooltip( 'confirm', 'confirm', 'click' );
tt.controller = 'ConfirmCtrl';
return tt;
```

And you have to tweak your Popopver template so they can call your controller method

```
<button class="btn-block btn btn-danger" ng-click="$parent.confirm()">Confirm </button>
```

The latest piece is to call the confirm handler from your controller

```
var fn = $parse($attrs.confirmHandler);

$scope.confirm = function(){
  fn($scope);
  $scope.tt_isOpen  = false;
};
```

Hope it helps!
I'm not an angular expert, so any comments / feedback about that method are welcome.